# Is there an efficient way to determine a distance?

Tags: c++, algorithm, scientific-computing

This question is more about the algorithm and the right use of function rather than the actual code.

In my code, I'm using map to simulate boxes. The maps elements are composed of `vector<int>` as keys and `set<shared_ptr<foo> >` as values.

I'm doing a nested loop to go over all the boxes:

```
mit1 = boxes.begin(); //mit1 is an appropriate iterator
int edge = 10;//represnd periodic boundary conditions
while (mit1 != boxes.end()){
  vector<t> = mit1->first;
  mit2 = mit1++;
  while (mit2 != boxes.end()){
    vector<int> u = (mit2++)->first;
    bool good = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3 && good; i++){
      u[i] = (int)fabs(u[i] - t[i]);
      good = u[i] == 0 || u[i] == 1 || u[i] == edge;
    }
    if (!good) continue;
  }
}
```

My concern is with the whole nested loop as well as the `for` loop. 
Would you consider it to be more efficient to have a function to calculate all the neighboring boxes? Do you know of any better way to do the for loop test?

Comment: Definitely there has to be a better way !!

Comment: What are you trying to calculate? And are you sure you didn't confuse between mit2 and u (or in other words - that you do not have an infinite loop in the second while)?

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the loop and should be fine now... I want to eliminate all the case where the two boxes are so for from one enother so there is no chance that the particles within the boxes are interacting. The box size is fixed to such a distance but I am left with the boxes distance calculation

Comment: It's great that you would show some code, but... insufficient. First things first, you should describe *the problem* you are trying to solve, *with context*, and then only show us what is bothering you. I'm still trying to understand if you want the distances between boxes or particles...

Comment: @Maththieu M: I don't show the code becouse it doesn't matter. I am considering the distance between the boxes which possition is determained by the first element of each member of the map. I have only menioned the particles to emphesize (and failed doing so) that the box approach is, in effect, thiton's solution. The box are fixed in space but their size and ammount is changing and most of them are empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same advice as with every collision detection: Use some algorithm or data structure that allows you to pre-filter candidates for your loop by their spatial distance, and allows to do this pre-filtering in O(n). A quad tree comes to mind, or a coarse-grained spatial map.

Edit: To make the whole idea a little bit clearer, consider the following algorithm: You have N particles in a 3D space and want to find out which particles are closer than a distance D to each other. You build a 3D array, with each bin representing a cubic volume of your target space, and each volume must be at least of size D. To find all particles that might be closer than D to a given particle X, you determine the array cell Ax in which X is currently and select all particles from the Ax and all surrounding cells. You only need to check this small subset for collisions.

When using M array cells, the average-case computational complexity for the whole distance check is now O(N*N/M) instead of O(N^2), however at the cost of O(M^2) space.

If your target space is unbounded, use a quad tree (2D) or an oct tree (3D).

Comment: This is why the boxes are there. Each box contain particle and the box are the filter. However, I still want to find a way which is both easy to understand and efficient...

Comment: Reading your edit... this is exactly what I am doing. The only difference is that the volume is changing hance I can't simply create a table where I am writing down all the pairs or so. Also, most of the volume is empty and it won't be efficient to go over all the boxes...

Comment: a) Quad/oct-trees are very good for such empty volumes. b) The check for 26 empty boxes is very cheap compared to comparing distances between all your objects. c) Again, with changing volumes, use oct-trees for the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified version of the general collision / mindist problem. Those problems get particularly nasty when you have a bunch of objects, each described by many polygonal faces.  There isn't a one size fits all solution to these problems. There are lots of heuristics that help attack this problem. A few of them:

- Use bounding spheres as well as bounding boxes. The distance between a pair of spheres is a lot easier to calculate than the distance between a pair of boxes, and the distance between a pair of bounding spheres is never more than the distance between a pair of bounding boxes. This lets you rule out lots and lots of calculations fairly quickly.
- Use a hierarchy of objects. If objects A, B, C, and D are always in close proximity to one another it is oftentimes useful to create a metaobject that contains A, B, C, and D. If you can rule out considering this metaobject as a candidate you have just ruled out consider any of the objects within as a candidate.
- If the objects are moving slowly, the nearest neighbor at the next step is oftentimes the nearest neighbor at the current step. Start with this as the first guess, then search other nearby objects, then go further abroad. Eventually (typically sooner than later) you will ruled out all the remaining objects.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your program is doing...

But it's possible to calculate the distance when a box moves. 
Then it optimizes some if not all boxes are moving.